# ggalluvial package in R - Setting alluvial fill color axis by axis (rather than solely by final axis)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization

I am currently trying to produce an alluvial plot in R with the [`ggalluvial` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/index.html).  With it I wish to plot the successive migration across multiple between different values across successive segments of time (Seg1, Seg2, Seg3, Seg4). At Seg 1 all cases have the value of "workseg"; at Seg 2 the value may be one of three other values (related content, unrelated content, NONE); Seg3 and Seg4 values can be any of the four options.

Using the following code...

```
##Reorder levels per segment (make vertical order of strata levels identical 
across all axes, rather than "zig-zag" --> this is just an aesthetic 
preference)##

dRG.lode <- dRG %>%
  mutate(Seg2 = factor(Seg2, levels=c("workseg", "related content", 
"unrelated content", "NONE")),
         Seg3 = factor(Seg3, levels=c("workseg", "related content", 
"unrelated content", "NONE")),
         Seg4 = factor(Seg4, levels=c("workseg", "related content", 
"unrelated content", "NONE")))


##Plot##

ggplot(as.data.frame(dRG.lode),
       aes(axis1 = Seg1, axis2 = Seg2, axis3 = Seg3, axis4 = Seg4)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Seg4), width = 1/12) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Seg1", "Seg2", "Seg3", "Seg4"), expand = 
c(.05, .05, .05, .05)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  ggtitle("Time Course, Segment by Segment")
```

...I have been able to produce the following plot:

[image: ...enter image description here]

My main question:

1) Is there a means by which to have the alluvial fill color not be consistent across an entire alluvial strand from start to finish, based on the Seg4 value, but INSTEAD to have the color change axis by axis, based upon the current axis value?  For instance, **I'd like all strands with a strata value of "workseg" at a given axis to be blue between that axis and the previous axis.**  Something akin to this seems possible based upon the vaccinations example at the bottom of [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html) (see last plot above appendix). The fills in that example reflect the strata they each came from, axis to axis (e.g., all strands coming from a "Never" strata are teal, regardless of their value at the next axis).  I basically want to implement the inverse of this - that is, fill based on the strata of the ***next*** axis (e.g., all strands leading to a "workseg" strata are blue, regardless of where their value at the previous axis).

An unrelated, secondary question:

2) Is there any means by which to add annotation to alluvia?  That is, they axes contain strata labels based upon values in the data set, but is there a means by which to add labels or other annotative information to the strands themselves (beyond manually in post-production)?

Comment: It's good that you can recognize that there are 2 separate questions at play. It's easier to help if you make them actually 2 questions; you can split the part about labels into another reproducible post

Comment: Can you provide a MCVE for this problem? With reproducible data & preferably fewer axes / strata that reflect what you are trying to do?

Comment: @camille Thanks; I'll create a second post for question 2 with updated descriptions and code sample once question 1 is resolved (to reduce chance of have two independently working but irreconcilable solutions :) ).

Comment: @Z.Lin Thanks.  The data can be found [here](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/YbtqVilCed).  As number of axes/strata, this is already a minimal set, though I can provide a MCVE with fewer arguments, streamlining consideration (next comment).

Comment: `ggplot(as.data.frame(mydata), aes(axis1 = Seg1, axis2 = Seg2, axis3 = Seg3, axis4 = Seg4)) + geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Seg4)) + geom_label(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE) + scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Seg1", "Seg2", "Seg3", "Seg4"))`

Adjusting the fill value changes the alluvial coloring.  I'm not sure if this argument alone can accomplish my goal or if additional arguments need to be considered (see code for vaccination example linked in original post).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the vaccinations example, flows adopt aesthetics from the strata to their lefts via `geom_flow()` with `fill = response` (the stratum variable); this can't be done using `geom_alluvium()`, which renders each complete alluvium as a single graphical object ("grob"). The data you've linked to are in what **ggalluvial** considers "wide" format, i.e. each axis is a variable, but in order to have a consistent stratum variable the data need to be in "long" format.

The code below makes both of these changes and uses `aes.flow = "backward"` (see [the documentation](http://corybrunson.github.io/ggalluvial/reference/geom_flow.html)) to have flows adopt aesthetics from the strata to their rights (instead of their lefts).

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

dRG <- read.csv("~/Downloads/mydata.csv")

dRG.lode <- dRG %>%
  mutate(Seg2 = factor(Seg2, levels=c("workseg", "related content", 
                                      "unrelated content", "NONE")),
         Seg3 = factor(Seg3, levels=c("workseg", "related content", 
                                      "unrelated content", "NONE")),
         Seg4 = factor(Seg4, levels=c("workseg", "related content", 
                                      "unrelated content", "NONE")))

dRG.long <- to_lodes_form(dRG.lode, -X,
                          key = "segment", value = "value", id = "id")

ggplot(dRG.long,
       aes(x = segment, stratum = value, alluvium = id)) +
  geom_flow(aes(fill = value), width = 1/12, aes.flow = "backward") +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Seg1", "Seg2", "Seg3", "Seg4"), expand = 
                     c(.05, .05, .05, .05)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  ggtitle("Time Course, Segment by Segment")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

On reflection, the naming conventions for the parameter `aes.flow` and its options `"forward"` and `"backward"` might not be the most intuitive. I'd welcome suggestions on that!

Comment: This is fantastic, @Cory; many thanks!  Some quick follow-ups:   1) The "-X" argument for the dRG.long assignment resulted in the error "object 'X' not found".  Removing this argument worked, however.   2) My resulting plot no longer vertically orders the strata per axis as intended (e.g., workseg, related, unrelated, none); could this be related to the above omission?   3) I assume not, but is it possible to set custom colors for each flow value (beyond the pre-set palettes) or for individual axis strata (rather than for the entire axis)?  Thanks again.

Comment: @jjcii glad this helps. (1) and (2) sound like version problems; if you update the three packages (**dplyr**, **ggplot2**, **ggalluvial**) and run the code again, do you see the same behavior? (3) should be possible using [`scale_fill_manual()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html).

Comment: @jjcii i only responded to the first half of (3); sorry. You can use different colors for the same values at different axes by [passing `discern = TRUE` in `to_lodes_form()`](http://corybrunson.github.io/ggalluvial/reference/alluvial-data.html), which i think is what you're after. Note that the documentation calls this parameter but does not use it in the way you have in mind, so you'll have to see for yourself if it does what you want.

Comment: Thanks, @Cory! With that info I was able to tackle (1), (2), and the first part of (3) successfully.  As for the `discern` argument, setting it to TRUE in the `to_lodes_form()` function results in following when attempting the plot: "Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 12 needed but only 4 provided."  I've set four colors via a pre-set vector, as recommended for the `scale_manual` guide (thanks!), but evidently the function is asking for a value for each strata of each axis.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @jjcii that's actually what i thought you wanted — a different color for each flow, even flows associated with the same value, when they appear at different axes. Is that not correct? If you leave out `discern = TRUE`, do you get what you want?

Comment: Ah, my mistake for not being clear, @Cory.  In the second part of (3) above, I meant to ask whether there is a means by which to set different fills for each vertical stratum comprising the axes themselves.  For instance, with the code above, the stratum fill is set to black.  Is it possible to set a unique color for "workseg", "related content", etc. that would be applied to all axes?

Comment: @jjcii yes, try removing `fill = "black"` in `geom_stratum()` and adding `aes(fill = value)` as the first argument. Alternatively, remove the `fill` parameter from both geoms (the `geom_*()` functions) and add `fill = value` to the `aes()` call inside `ggplot()`; it should then be passed to both geoms.

Comment: Thanks, @Cory, that works perfectly. I have two quick, *final* questions (sorry): 1) `geom_stratum` includes a color argument to set the color of the strata borders; is possible to set individual colors per stratum border in a single axis?  2) Is is possible to insert a line break in the stratum label text?

Comment: @jjcii For (1), the `color` aesthetic behaves the same way as `fill`; the common behavior of the aesthetic specifications is part of the "grammar" of **ggplot2**. For (2), perhaps your motivating question is addressed in [this vignette](http://corybrunson.github.io/ggalluvial/articles/labels.html). The **ggfittext** package facilitates text-wrapping, though it's not in the vignette.

Comment: Thanks, @Cory.  More particular than fit-based text-wrapping, I'm hoping to pre-set line breaks in label text as a hack for denoting a secondary piece of information beyond the value text (so something like "workseg [/linebreak/] extra text").  I'll search further, as a solution will likely also be at the grammar level or yet another package extension.  Thanks again!

Comment: @jjcii i don't know how to do that myself, but if you find it useful then i'd be glad to know about it — it may be worth adding to the vignette. (Consider opening an issue on GitHub if so.) Glad to have helped!